# Plasma Discover stuck at 100% while installing a snap

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, kde, snap, 18.10

I tried installing the RetroArch snap from within Plasma Discover. It is now stuck at "RetroArch - Installing: 0 B/s". What should I do?

Comment: Open a terminal if you can and run `pkill plasma-discover`

Comment: Ok, I did that. Now what? Is there a way to verify or fix broken snap packages?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use snaps or flatpaks! For that matter, I don't even use Plasma Discover. If you really need this RetroArch snap, please see if you can install it via the terminal. That maybe a surer route.